# Different background color for each selection in a list

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating a list and I need a different background color for each item in the list. With the code I have the background color is white. I am missing something.

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    namespace App5
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
        public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = new ListItem[] {

        new ListItem {Title ="Red", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Red},
        new ListItem {Title ="Orange", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Orange},
        new ListItem {Title ="Yellow", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow},
        new ListItem {Title ="Green", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Green},
        new ListItem {Title ="Blue", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Blue},
        new ListItem {Title ="Violet", ForeColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Violet}
        };


        listView.RowHeight = 80;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListItemCell));
        Content = listView;

        listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) => {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)e.Item;
            await DisplayAlert("Tapped", item.Title.ToString() + " was selected.", "Ok");
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        };
    }
    class ListItemCell : ViewCell
    {
        public ListItemCell()
        {
            Label titleLabel = new Label
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                FontSize = 25,
                FontAttributes = Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes.Bold,
                TextColor = Color.White
            };
            titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

            StackLayout viewLayoutItem = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = { titleLabel}
            };

            StackLayout viewLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Padding = new Thickness(25, 10, 55, 15),
                Children = { viewLayoutItem }
            };
            View = viewLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Ok, after more research I realized I missing binding for the forecolor and background color. Off to figure that piece out now.

Comment: When you ask a question there is a button that highlights code

Comment: You can post your solution as answer and mark it so that more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was missing. I took out the forecolor because I was able to set the text color differently, since all the text was just one color.

As for the background, I was missing this:

viewLayout.SetBinding(StackLayout.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor");

Now it works :)